# Update/delete queries cannot be typed JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entitymanager, sql-delete

I'm using the Spring framework for working on training projects. I'm also using JPA and have been having a hell of a time. In my DAO implementation class, I've written:

```
@Override
public void deleteEntries(Module mod) {
    System.out.println(mod.getDescription());
    entityManager.createQuery("delete from TrainingEntry e where e.module = :mod and e.completedDate IS NULL",
                              TrainingEntry.class).setParameter("mod", mod);

}
```

As you can see it's just a simple DELETE statement, but I get the error:

```
"Update/delete queries cannot be typed."
```

My guess is, that I need to use some of the `EntityManager` class methods to do the job, but I'm not certain, as there's next to nothing about this error online. I'm also having difficulty applying some solutions I've found online about JPA delete queries. Any point in the right direction or explanation as to why this error is thrown is much appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The declaration of the [`EntityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) methods are the following:

```
Query createQuery(java.lang.String qlString)
<T> TypedQuery<T> createQuery(java.lang.String qlString, java.lang.Class<T> resultClass)
// The other three method is not relevant here
```

From this, you can clearly see, that you get a `TypedQuery<T>` because of the second parameter. If you remove it, you will get a simple `Query` object. That is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Marking it answered as it got rid of the error. Still doesn't like my query but at least progress has been made.

Answer (score 13):

Try removing the `TrainingEntry.class` argument when calling createQuery(), since this is what makes it a "typed" query.

Comment: Hi David, what does that second argument (ClassName.class) we generally put indicates ?

Comment: @AshutoshTiwari It's the type of the returned objects. But since update and delete queries do not return row objects, it should not be included for those.

Answer (score 1):

```
entityManager.createQuery("delete from TrainingEntry e where e.module = :mod and e.completedDate IS NULL").setParameter("mod", mod);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.