# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Update/delete queries cannot be typed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to create SQL query for deleting rows. I tried this:

```
public void deleteByIds(List<Integer> ids)
{
        String hql = "delete from " + OnboardingTasks.class.getName() + " e WHERE e.id IN :ids";
        TypedQuery<OnboardingTasks> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, OnboardingTasks.class).setParameter("ids", ids);
        query.executeUpdate();
}
```

But I get exception: `ption [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Update/delete queries cannot be typed] with root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Update/delete queries cannot be typed` 
Do you know what is the proper way to send a list of Id's to delete?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update/delete queries cannot be typed JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439141/update-delete-queries-cannot-be-typed-jpa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TypedQuery<X>` is a query that yields a return object of the type `X` or a list thereof.
Update and delete queries don't return anything, so you have to use a different type of query for them.

Using `EntityManager.createQuery(String)` instead of `EntityManager.createQuery(String, Class)` should do the trick.

Comment: That is deprecated though.